# Convert keys from string to int type in python dictionary with mixed key types

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary-comprehension

Consider a python dictionary that has mixed key types:

```
chrDict = {'1':234,'12':45,'23':121,'2':117,'chX':12,'chY':32}
```

I want to convert those keys in string type into int type which are numeric and leave the rest. The result I expect is:

```
chrDict = {1:234,12:45,23:121,2:117,'chX':12,'chY':32}
```

I tried the following:

```
chrDict.update((int(i),j) for i,j in chrDict.items())
```

This gives me the error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a 
sequence
```

Then I tried:

```
for i,j in chrDict.items():
    try:
        chrDict.update(int(x),y)
    except:
        pass
```

But the output I get is not correct, it doesn't change:

```
{'1': 234, '12': 45, '23': 121, '2':117, 'chX': 12, 'chY': 32}
```

Actually I want this to do so that it becomes easier to sort later. Currently if i try:

```
sorted(chrDict.items())
```

It gives me following output:

```
[('1', 234), ('12', 45), ('2', 117), ('23', 121), ('chX', 12), ('chY', 32)]
```

The key value `2` should come after key value `1` which is not happening.

So please give me some suggestions to tackle this problem. Is there any better approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension with `isdigit()` to check for strings that are actually numbers:

```
{int(k) if k.isdigit() else k: v for k, v in chrDict.items()}
```

**Example**:

```
chrDict = {'1':234,'12':45,'23':121,'2':117,'chX':12,'chY':32}

print({int(k) if k.isdigit() else k: v for k, v in chrDict.items()})
# {1: 234, 12: 45, 23: 121, 2: 117, 'chX': 12, 'chY': 32}
```

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions on sorting of the final dict , so that number keys line up properly and character keys don't give an error?

Comment: @Ashutosh you're sorting them as strings in your code, not as integers. As far as strings go, `12` comes before `2`. Try converting them to integers first.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Austin's post answers your specific query.  Note that this is creating a new dictionary (not editing your current dictionary in place).

Further, Python cannot compare type **int** to type **str** to sort a list containing both data types (this will raise a TypeError in Python 3) - so you may wish to consider a different approach, if your ultimate goal is to have a sorted list of mixed data types (or create your own custom comparison).